Restrict Dynamic Type to scale to the container's dimension
I have a library of SwiftUI Components that is being developed to be integrated in other projects across many other products of the company. The UI component library serves as the design system.
I am trying to achieve Dynamic Type for the Text labels in SwiftUI. I am using a custom font and I want to be able to restrict the dynamic type to its container's dimensions (width and height).
I have already used the font modifier as following:
.font(dynamicScaling ? .custom(style.name, size: style.size, relativeTo: style.dynamicTypeMapping) : .custom(style.name, fixedSize: style.size))

I have created the following for styling the Text:
protocol TextStyling {
    associatedtype Body: View
    func body(text: Text) -> Body
}

struct CustomTextStyle: TextStyling {
    var styleCategory: StyleCategory
    var dynamicScalingEnabled: Bool = true
    var customFont: CustomFont {
        return CustomFontManager.font(style: styleCategory)
    }
    
    func body(text content: Text) -> some View {
        return content
            .font(dynamicScalingEnabled ? .custom(customFont.name, size: customFont.size, relativeTo: customFont.dynamicTypeReference) : .custom(customFont.name, fixedSize: customFont.size))
            .underline(customFont.underline)
            .lineSpacing((customFont.lineHeight / customFont.fontHeight) * customFont.fontHeight - customFont.fontHeight)
    }
}

extension Text {
    func applyStyle<TS: TextStyling>(_ style: TS) -> some View {
        return style.body(text: self)
    }

    public func customStyle(styleCategory: StyleCategory, dynamicScalingEnabled: Bool = true) -> some View {
        applyStyle(CustomTextStyle(styleCategory: styleCategory, dynamicScalingEnabled: dynamicScalingEnabled))
    }
}

One of my use case is satisfied, when I use .custom(style.name, fixedSize: style.size). This completely turns off the dynamic scaling when needed.
When dynamic scaling is enabled and I increase the Accessibility -> Large Text setting, the text overflows the container and increases the container height/width.
The medium sized text looks like this:

When I increase the Large Text setting, the font scales up:

Ideally, I would want to restrict the font scaling to this scale even if the Large Text setting is turned to max:

How can I achieve this?

If I understand correctly, you want the maximum dynamic type size to be xLarge? How about .dynamicTypeSize(...DynamicTypeSize.xLarge)?

I have to support iOS 14+ so can't use dynamicTypeSize but I have tried using the equivalent .environment(\.sizeCategory, .xLarge).
The problem I face with this approach is that I do not know what would be the container size at the runtime and the sizeCategory could be .large or .xxLarge that would fit the container.

You should be able to acheive this using .minimumScaleFactor https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/minimumscalefactor
eg.
    func body(text content: Text) -> some View {
        return content
            .font(dynamicScalingEnabled ? .custom(customFont.name, size: customFont.size, relativeTo: customFont.dynamicTypeReference) : .custom(customFont.name, fixedSize: customFont.size))
            .underline(customFont.underline)
            .lineSpacing((customFont.lineHeight / customFont.fontHeight) * customFont.fontHeight - customFont.fontHeight)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
    }

This will allow the text to shrink up to 90% of the size requested by dynamic font sizing, but will only do so after the container size is filled.
